# godaddy create stored procedure in mysql hosting

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, shared-hosting

I have hosted a website in godaddy with php/mysql/apache. Now I want to create stored procedure in mysql but find that no options in cPanel for me to do. When I just paste the create sql in cPanel SQL window, it said it need super privileges to do that. After google in the website, it said I can remote connect to godaddy mysql and create in my mysql console workbench. But when I setup in the mysql console, it said it cannot connect after test connection. What should I do? What is the correct steps to do that??

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure your stored procedures are labeled as **DETERMINISTIC**.

This is an example of an allowed stored procedure form Godaddy help pages :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spGetSouls`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `spGetSouls`()
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM soul;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL spGetSouls();
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with your account- I was able to create stored procedures on mine. In cPanel, I picked phpMyAdmin and selected on of my databases. There'll be a "Routines" tab showing. I created a new routine (type of procedure) to create a stored procedure and it saved successfully. If this isn't working for you, I'd suggest opening a support ticket

Using MySQL work bench would be the best option. You should be able to connect with the same hostname/IP that shows in cPanel. Try opening a command prompt and running the following:

```
telnet <cpanel_account_ip> 3306
```

That should be working (just tested and mine works great). If it's not, you might have a firewall rule blocking it.  When you use Workbench, make sure you connect with the database user defined under the MySQL databases. You may need to associate that user with the database (which you can also do from the MySQL databases page in cPanel).

Let us know how it works out!